# Laravel4 - HTML5 Form: Keep many lines instead of put everything in one line

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have made a simple form for contact:

```
    <form name="mailsend" method="post" action="index.php"> 
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME"> 
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="YOUR E-MAIL"> 
      <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="5" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="button">Contact me</button>
    </form>
```

I save the message entered:
     $message = $input['message'];
and then i send it to the mail.

The question is that if someone write 5 lines of texts, i will receive the message in one line without new paragraphs.
How can i keep the text as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert new line characters to break,

```
$message = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r/", "<br />",  $input['message']);
$message = trim($message]);
```

Or

```
$message = nl2br($input['message']);
$message = trim($message])
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick question ... if you have a "max" validation constraint, won't `nl2br($input['message'])` break that? For the user, one new line (while typing) is one character. But nl2br will effectively change newline to a break tag that's 5 characters long.